# Optional groups in regex

Tags: regex

I am trying do a regex for this cases:

```
1) Any title    
2) Any title (2016)    
3) Any title (2016 Any text)
```

I need the text before the parenthesis(title) and the year inside(year). Example for the cases:

1)

```
Title: Any title   
Year: null
```

2)

```
Title: Any title   
Year: 2016
```

3)

```
Title: Any title   
Year: 2016
```

I do this regex:

```
(.*)(?:\s(\((\d+)(?:\D*)?)\))?
```

But dont work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could go for:

```
^                   # start of the string
(?P<title>[^\n()]+) # anything not a (, ) or newline -> "title"
(?:                 # non-capturing group
    \(              # ( literally
    (?P<year>\d{4}) # four digits -> "year"
    [^)]*\)         # anything not ), followed by )
)?                  # make the whole group optional
```

See [**a demo on regex101.com**](https://regex101.com/r/8CuTD9/1).
If named captured groups are not supported (you did not specify any programming language), just omit the `?P<>` part and use the group numbers `1` and `2` instead.